# bash grep for a mix of special characters some of which to be interpreted literally

Tags: bash, grep, special-characters

I have `data.txt` that has the following format

```
blah<TAB>string1_with_spaces_quotes_dots_etc<TAB>blah
blah<TAB>string2_with_spaces_quotes_dots_etc<TAB>blah
...
```

Some of the `stringJ_...` appear more than once. The file is not sorted in any way.

I also have `strings.txt` that have the form

```
stringA_with_spaces_quotes_dots_etc
stringC_with_spaces_quotes_dots_etc
stringB_with_spaces_quotes_dots_etc
...
```

These strings appear only once but this file is not sorted either.

**What I need is, for every string from `strings.txt` find lines in `data.txt` where the middle string is exactly the one from `strings.txt`.** So, for example, if the string I am looking for is

```
foo.
```

Then I need to extract the following lines

```
blah<TAB>foo.<TAB>blah
```

but not lines like

```
blah<TAB>foo. bar<TAB>blah
blah<TAB>foo<TAB>blah
```

The difficulty here is that those strings can have characters like dots that can be interpreted as special chars, while I need literal matches.

What is the right set of `grep` options in the loop below? Or should I use a different command altogether?

```
while read t
do
     grep <OPTIONS> "\t${t}\t" data.txt
done < strings.txt
```

Comment: Have you read the man page. It explains how to match literal strings.

Comment: `grep -F` or `fgrep`.

Comment: It looks like both fgrep (and grep -F) will also keep the \t from being expanded into a tab.  In vi and in the shell itself, you can use ^V<TAB> (hit Control-V and then the Tab key) to insert a literal tab into your code, and then fgrep should behave...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you get beyond simple regexp matching (e.g. anything involving targeting a specific column/field), you want awk, not grep:

```
awk -F'\t' 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} $2 in a' strings.txt data.txt
```

The above does string matching, not regexp matching, so there are no "special characters" and is entirely focused on matching on the whole of the 2nd tab-separated field of data.txt so there are no partial or other false matches possible. It will only match exactly what you want.

Also, any time you're considering writing a shell loop to manipulate text, read https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice to understand some, but not all, of the reasons why you shouldn't.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I am definitely guilty of doing a lot of "loop though text"

Comment: Yeah, most people start out doing that as it seems quick and easy at first then over time you discover it's immensely slow and fragile and has zero benefits over doing it the right way...

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-f` and `-F` flags together.

```
grep -f strings.txt -F data.txt
```

`-f` treats each line of `strings.txt` as a separate pattern, while `-F` performs string matching, not regular-expression matching.

Comment: But if I do this, won't I get a bunch of false matches? For example, if I search for `foo.`, I'll also get `foo. bar` etc. That's the reason I want to use the tabs before and after the string in the `grep` above

Comment: Add the tabs to `strings.txt`.